# Mixins Gradient for IE8

Tags: css, less, mixins

I am trying to make some LESS Mixin for graditent that will wotk in IE8, i know i can use gradient in IE8 like this

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

This is juwt example, but what i need to make some custom mixin that will create that for IE8, this is CSS what i have

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.08) 0%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.08) 0%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.08) 0%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.08) 0%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.08) 0%);
```

What i need is to modified my LESS mixins that i created

```
.gradient (@startColor: #eee, @endColor: white) {
    background-color: @startColor;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
}
```

For support for IE8 :)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@startColor', endColorstr='@endColor',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

But the problem is here
**'@startColor'**

In brackets, it does not recognize the variable

Comment: You need to use it like `startColorstr='@{startColor}'` instead of `startColorstr='@startColor'` (note the curly braces). When you don't use the curly braces, Less compiler treats the value within quotes simply as text and not as a variable.

Answer (score -1):

The traditional LESS compiler will not accept the filter property and will throw you an error. You simply use LESS Escaping for this problem as well. all you need to do is add the following line in your gradient and it should work just fine.

```
filter: ~”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{startColor},
endColorstr='@{endColor})”;
```

This line will appear as it is in the code.